# Inconsistent Download Speeds

Tags: google-chrome, download, task-manager, file-download

I am downloading a fairly large file (~2G). The download speed that chrome is showing is varying from 300-600kbps. What is confusing me is that the windows task manager is showing speeds varying from 2-5Mbps. Nothing is else downloading and I'm not doing anything else on chrome (until now I'm asking this question which hasn't affected those numbers). What is causing these two calculated download speeds to be so different?

Comment: Provide screenshots of what you mean precisely.  I suspect your getting confused, because one is being displayed in another unit, just want to make sure.

Comment: first, confirm that those 'b's are all lower case. 5Mbps is about 655KBps (kiloBytes vs megaBits).  [5*1048567bits]/8 == 655360 Bytes. [2*1048567bits]/8 == 262144 Bytes. seems to match up if we assume that Chrome is showing your Bytes not bits.

Comment: You're right, one is bytes and one is bits. Silly oversight on my part. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two speeds are nearly the same. The speed shows by the Task Manager is in mega*bits* per second, while that shown by Chrome is in kilo*bytes* per second. Since 1 Byte= 8 bits, both speeds are nearly the same. One more thing is that the speed shown by the task manager is the overall downloading speed, i.e. the downloading speed of Chrome plus other background downloads by Windows. That's why sometimes the two speeds differ by a small fraction.
Hope it satisfies you... :)